# Which data structure to store co-authorship?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, jung

I have a list of authors with title of the book and the year of publication, for example:

*Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea: Java Concurrency in Practice, 2006*

Ken Arnold, James Gosling and David Holmes: Java Programming Language, 2005

...

I was wondering what data structure would be best to store information about co-authors, book they have written together and year of publication.

I would like to later use this information to draw graphs (in [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), I'm using java), where each author would be node and the edge would be each book they co-authored. Separate graph would be drawn for every year. I was thinking of using multimap:

```
Map<Year, Map<Author, List<Map<Co-author, Title>>>>
```

but maybe this is overcomplicated?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

How about placing a set of authors and title in an object, named, for example, 'Book'? That way, your data structures could be simply

```
class Book {
    List<Author> authors;
    Title title;
}

Map<Year, Set<Book>> booksInYears
```

The graph-drawing algorithm could work like this:

```
for (Book book : booksInYears.get(aYear)) 
    for (Author author1 : book.authors) 
        for (Author author2 : book.authors) 
            if (author1 != author2) 
                drawEdge(author1, author2, book.title);
```

`drawEdge` method would first check if both authors have corresponding nodes already drawn (for example using a set containing authors with already drawn nodes, or perhaps an Author => Node map) and draw needed nodes, and then draw an edge between them.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a JUNG graph out of it; JUNG will handle the data structures.  That is, nodes will be Authors and edges will be Coauthor relationships (which would consist of information about the work).

That said, having worked with co-authorship graphs in the past, you may want to consider the more natural representation of coauthorship as either a bipartite graph (Authors vs Works) or a hypergraph.  That way you don't need to redundantly represent the work multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is a bad idea to structure your data like that, why not use the polymorphism concept?

Why not creating `Class Book` , containing stuff like year of publication, name etc..
Than create another entity such as `Class Author`, and construct between the two **Book** will contain `List<Author>` coAuthors , and **Author** can contain `List<Book>`